# How to apply continuous functional calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

This is the statement I am using.

> [Theorem 2.17, pg 34:](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf) Suppose that $A$ is a unital $C^*$ algebra and that $a$ is a normal element in $A$, then there is a $*$-isometric isomorphism 
>   $$C(\sigma(a)) \rightarrow C^*(\{1_A, a \}) \subseteq A$$
>   such that $id \mapsto a$, where $id$ is the identity function on $\Bbb C$.

I want apply this result to a bounded operator $T$ on Hilbert space $H$.

> If $T \in B(H)$ is normal, and $\sigma(a)$ is discrete, then the "spike" functions, 
>   $$\delta_\lambda(x):=
> \begin{cases}
> 1 \text{ if } \lambda =x \\ 
> 0 \text{ otherwise } 
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Maps to the projection map $$\delta_\lambda(T)= P_\lambda$$
>   the projection map on to the eigenspaces.

This seems intuitively true. But I don't know how to prove it.

The problem may not  be well defined too, since we do not know that the eigenspaces are in fact closed - let us suppose this to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions satisfy $ x\delta_\lambda(x)=\lambda\delta_\lambda(x)$. So you have 
$$
TP_\lambda=\lambda P_\lambda. 
$$
This shows that any element in the range of $P_\lambda$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector for $T$.

Conversely, if $Tv=\lambda v$, we get that $p(T)v=p(\lambda)v$ for any polynomial $p$ that has $p(0)=0$. By taking a sequence $\{p_n\}$ of polynomials such that $p_n\to\delta_\lambda$ uniformly (recall that the spectrum of $T$ is discrete), we obtain 
$$
\delta_\lambda(T)v=\delta_\lambda(\lambda)v,
$$
which is $P_\lambda v=v$. Thus $P_\lambda$ is the projection onto the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $T$.

The eigenspaces are always closed, they are kernels of bounded operators.